# How much of a drag is it, orbiting the Earth in a space suit?

Tags: spacesuits, atmospheric-drag, eva

An astronaut in a spacesuit travels around the Earth at the same altitude as the ISS. Let's say the astronaut leads the ISS by 1000 meters *along the same orbit*.

After one orbit, how much velocity has the astronaut *lost or gained* with respect to the ISS due to atmospheric drag? How much *closer or farther* will they be?

Assume a quiet sun.

Assume the astronaut is in any configuration you like; prone, broadside, or tumbling, curled up, etc.

Comment: re the wording of the title: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OusADDs_3ps and [as text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother%27s_Little_Helper#Lyrics_and_composition)

Comment: The force due to drag will be proportional to the cross-sectional area of the object, while the acceleration will be inversely proportional to the mass. Essentially, this question boils down to a comparison of the area/mass ratio for an astronaut and the ISS.

Comment: @NuclearWang That sounds about right; assume some nominal solar panel tilt or some average from the ISS' B-star from some TLE.

Comment: You could probably find some information related to SuitSat (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuitSat)

Comment: The difference in drag seems to be so small that working outside the ISS is possible.

Comment: Two words: ballistic coefficient.

Comment: @OrganicMarble So for the ISS there seems to be at least a few ways to get the ballistic coefficient. 1) estimate the geometrical cross-sectional area of the ISS and find an answer here with the ISS' mass, 2) find a "space scholar" with library of report on the ISS' who can find one on it's ballistic coefficient, or 3) Start with B-star from a TLE and [work backwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSTAR).

Comment: @Uwe or perhaps just the *magnitude of* drag is so small that working outside the ISS is possible.

Comment: The answer can be reasonably accurate only with a numerical simulation, but I saw that you simulated 3 astronauts, so this case is even easier. But if you are interested in another simulation, I'll be happy to post a "real case" result.

Comment: uhoh the ISS ballistic coefficient cannot be estimated from the BSTAR field because it's a fitting parameter (like any other TLE field). The most reliable way is to do a best fit (numerical integration and TLE+SGP4) for a short period of time (between two reboosts).

Comment: @Cristiano I'll go along with "*should* not be estimated from the BSTAR field", but I think "cannot" might be too strong a word. I think one can estimate it if one first estimates a density at the epoch times of the TLEs used. It might not be very close, but it would nonetheless count as an estimate, no? I suppose one could still call it an "unreasonable estimate".

Comment: @Cristiano as for a simulation-based answer, go for it! That would allow us to see just how unreasonable $$\frac{\rho_0}{2 \ B^*}$$ turns out to be ;-)

Comment: Oh! I got your point! :-) You can estimate BC also from a random number generator, but I doubt that it would be of any help. Ok for the simulation, I'll post some graphs.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s a “real case” simulation, in the sense that I read the ISS initial state from a TLE+SGP4, then I propagate that TLE forward in time until I find a point 1 km away from the initial state (that point is the astronaut and he is exactly along the ISS orbit).

The ISS ballistic coefficient is obtained from a best fit of the ISS position during two reboosts; I chose the TLEs from `20002.55629799` to `20023.25950111` (they are smooth enough to obtain a "stable" BC estimate). To calculate the initial states for this simulation I used the TLE `20005.24658230`.

After about 18 minutes, the program finds a ballistic coefficient of about $179\,kg/m^2$ (it’s not fixed, because the drag coefficient varies with the air composition), but keep in mind that it’s a fitting parameter (like the BSTAR used in the TLEs) and its value is good only for my simulation and I have no idea about its accuracy. If the simulation perfectly simulates the real world, the BC is exact, but since no simulation can be perfect, the BC is not exact.

The BC of the astronaut is simply calculated by putting mass= 90 kg, area= 1.8 x 0.8 = 1.44 m<sup>2</sup> and cd= 1.2 (but it varies with the air composition and I use an additional parameter to set that variation). The result of that variation is an average BC= $46.3\,kg/m^2$.

Without doing any calculation, we already know that the astronaut will decay faster than the ISS (the smaller the BC, the faster the decay rate) and the distance between the two objects will become greater and greater.

Unfortunately I cannot post a 3D graph here, but the following 3 graphs should explain what happens.

The first one should answer your question:

[image: distance /range rate]

it shows the distance between the ISS and the astronaut and the range rate. I plotted two orbits to show that the range rate tends to increase. With this particular TLE, the distance after 93 minutes (about 1 orbit) is 1009.289 m.

The second graph shows the ISS radius vector and the difference between the magnitude of the astronaut radius vector and the ISS radius vector (the astronaut flies lower than the ISS):

[image: radius vector]

The last graph shows the ISS ECI speed and the difference between the magnitude of the astronaut and ISS ECI velocities (the astronaut flies faster than the ISS in an inertial reference frame):

[image: velocities]

As a final note, here’s the usual details about the simulation.
It includes the Newtonian and the relativistic accelerations of all the planets, Sun and Moon.
The Earth's gravity field is modeled with the SGG-UGM-1 gravity model (computed using EGM2008 derived gravity anomaly and GOCE observation data) truncated to the degree and order 15.
For the calculation of the air density, I use the NRLMSISE-00 model along with an updated data file for the solar and geomagnetic indices: www.celestrak.com/spacedata/SW-All.txt.

**EDIT**: it seems interesting to me to add a graph of the drag:

[image: drag]

**EDIT #2**: following the OrganicMarble's comment, I calculated the RIC components (radial, intrack, crosstrack) of the astronaut.
While the radial and intrack components don't add any useful information (given the small distance between the objects, the radial component is about the same as ||Rsat|| - ||Riss|| and the intrack component is about the same as the distance between the two objects), the crosstrack component could be interesting:

[image: xtrack component]

I've extended the propagation to 10 orbits to show that the astronaut oscillates left and right of the ISS orbit, although after 10 orbits the oscillation is still less than 1 meter (xtrack > 0 is towards the angular momentum direction).

Comment: This is great stuff! In a station-centered frame, what would be the astronaut's motion?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think that you can consider the first graph as ISS-centered; in that frame, the graph shows the distance and the range rate of the astronaut wrt the ISS. But probably I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the motion of astronaut as seen by a camera on the ISS....does she drift more ahead, below, off the side, or what?

Comment: Ok, I could try to plot the RIC components (radial, in-track, cross track) of the astronaut wrt the ISS orbit.

Comment: Really nice! Thanks.

Comment: My question is "After one orbit, how much velocity has the astronaut lost or gained with respect to the ISS due to atmospheric drag? How much closer or farther will they be?" and your plots don't really provide a single readable number. We know that orbits around a realistic Earth are lumpy and wiggly, but there will be an overall loss in average altitude or velocity due to drag. With the BC that you've found, can you just give a value for the lost *average* velocity or altitude?

Comment: The question mentions that they are in the same orbit as the ISS but I didn't ask about the distance to the ISS, here the change in altitude would refer to the decrease in average distance to the Earth. Maybe it's 1 meter per orbit, or 100 meters per orbit, all I need is a ballpark estimate and your BC should be able to provide that.

Comment: @uhoh Did you wake up after 2 months? :) Probably the best way to answer your question (if I correctly understand your point) is to do the same simulation but w/o the atmosphere; but I need to rewrite the code...

Comment: @Cristiano I've added a simple answer. I'm curious how your calculation compares quantitatively.

Comment: @uhoh Tomorrow I'll post both the simulation w/o the atmosphere and the result of your procedure with the density obtained from the NRLMSISE-00 model.

Answer (score 2):

[I add another answer to avoid too much mess.]

Here are the graphs that show the differences in distance and speed with and w/o the atmosphere:

[image: Distance]

Distance with the atmosphere: 1008.3116 m
Distance w/o the atmosphere: 999.7882 m

[image: Speed]

||Vast|| - ||Viss|| with the atmosphere: 2.2493 mm/s
||Vast|| - ||Viss|| w/o the atmosphere: 0.6093 mm/s

**Your procedure**

Since the air density and C<sub>D</sub> are not constant, I need to integrate F<sub>D</sub> / m against the time.
Even if your value for the astronaut cross section is more realistic, I kept my value (1.44 m<sup>2</sup>).

$\Delta v_{ISS} = 0.381916\,mm/s$
$\Delta v_{astronaut} = 1.47378\,mm/s$

$x_{ISS} = 1.06555\,m$
$x_{astronaut} = 4.11185\,m$

Answer (score 0):

> How much of a drag is it, orbiting the Earth in a space suit?... After one orbit, how much velocity has the astronaut lost or gained with respect to the ISS due to atmospheric drag?

**tl;dr:** It depends on the mood that the Sun is in, but you'd loose about 23 meters per orbit or 340 meters per day at 400 km, plus/minus a factor of 10.

---

After looking at several images of astronauts outside the ISS and guessing at dimensions, I've come to the conclusion that a suited astronaut with full backpack (life support system) is at most about 2.0 square meters in cross section viewed from the back or front with arms and legs outstretched. Viewed top-down it's probably half that.

The [drag equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation) at high velocity is just

$$F_D = \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 C_D A.$$

With $a=F_D/m$ and $\Delta v = a \Delta t$ this becomes:

$$\Delta_v = \frac{F_D}{m} \Delta t = \frac{\rho v^2 C_D A \Delta t}{2m}.$$

Assuming 100 kg for the astronaut and hardware, a 92 minute orbit and $C_D$ of 1 and an orbital velocity of 7670 m/s at 400 km, all we need is the density. However this is by far the largest uncertainty.

At the ISS altitude of 400 km the website http://www.braeunig.us/space/atmos.htm (see also [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37597/12102)) gives 5E-13, 4E-12, and 5E-11 kg/m^3 for Low, Mean, and Extremely High solar activity.

If we choose the middle or Mean value we get $\Delta v$ of only 0.013 m/s per orbit.

That corresponds to a change in altitude of about 23 meters per orbit or 340 meters per day.

It will be about a factor of 10 faster or slower if the extremely high or low solar activity densities are assumed, about a factor of 2 slower if you can maintain a prone, head-first attitude.

> How much closer or farther will they be (to the ISS)?

Along track relative to the ISS we can use $x = \frac{1}{2} a t^2$ which ends up as $\frac{1}{2} v_{final} \Delta t$ which is about a 36 meter change if the ISS didn't lose any velocity, or zero if the ISS loses velocity at the same rate as the astronaut. To that I will defer to the [other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41422/12102) which examines the ISS' trajectory in detail.