# Is the Earth's orbit regulated?

Tags: orbit, law

Does somebody or some organization regulate the Earth's orbit? For example, could I send my project there by my own? Or do I have to ask someone for permission?

Comment: This is a similar question, and there may be other, similarly similar questions here as well; [How is space assigned for satellites that follow intersecting orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4876/12102)

Comment: Do you mean orbits around the Earth, or the orbit **of** the Earth?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Around, of course. It's strange to talk about sending something to orbit with the Earth around the sun.

Comment: Just going by what you wrote, not what you meant.